# Setting height and width of an Anko view to match_parent

Tags: android, layout, kotlin, anko

I would like to set the height and width of an video view to `match_parent`. My code looks something like the following. It works without the `height` and `width` attributes, but doing it as below give me a `val cannot be reassigned` error.

```
class VideoActivityUI : AnkoComponent<VideoActivity> {
    companion object {
        val ID_VIDEO = 11
    }

    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<VideoActivity>) = with(ui) {
        videoView{
            id = ID_VIDEO
            height = matchParent
            width = matchParent
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `videoView { layoutParams = OuterLayout.LayoutParams(matchParent, matchParent) ... `, where `OuterLayout` is a class of the layout, which is around this `VideoView`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `lparams` to set layout parameters, like this (you can omit the explicit parameter names if you want to):

```
videoView {
    id = ID_VIDEO
}.lparams (width = matchParent, height = matchParent)
```

Alternatively, you can do it like this:

```
videoView {
    id = ID_VIDEO
}.lparams {
    height = matchParent
    width = matchParent
}
```

The related wiki section for Anko can be found [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Layouts#layouts-and-layoutparams).

---

Note that you have to have a `ViewGroup` around your `VideoView` as the root of the `Activity`'s layout for it to have layout parameters available, because it gets different ones depending on whether it's in a `FrameLayout`, `LinearLayout`, or `RelativeLayout`.

For example, with a simple `frameLayout`, your code would look like this:

```
override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<VideoActivity>) = with(ui) {
    frameLayout {
        videoView {
            id = ID_VIDEO
        }.lparams(matchParent, matchParent)
    }
}
```

Comment: Both of those give me an `Unresolved references: lparams` error.

Comment: Ah, I see, it was a problem with VideoView specifically which also happens on the XML files. I'll accept this.